# BackBarButtonItem Not appear

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem

I have implemented a Navigation Controller to navigate between views (in Root View Controller).

In MainWindow.xib I have implemented a Navigation Bar but marking the option Hidden.

In other views I have used other Navigation Bar Object in the xib file and I used them to navigate between views. The problem is the Back button.

```
    UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                  initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                           target:nil 
                                                           action:@selector(back:)];

   navigItem.backBarButtonItem = backBtn;

   [self.navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navigItem]];
```

It does not appear the Back Button (arrow shaped)

Alternatively, I can use the Left Bar Button but it is not the same. This code runs:

```
    UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                  initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                           target:nil 
                                                           action:@selector(back:)];

   navigItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;

   [self.navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navigItem]];
```

My question:

Is possible to implement BackBarButtonItem when you use the Navigation Bar in Interface Builder but considering that in Root View Controller there is another Navigation Bar Controller (but Hidden)??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UINavigationController then you do not need to implement a UniavigationBar or nav items as you get this for free.

To set the back button text you can either set the title of the view the back button will return to ( and the back button on the view pushed on top will get this name) or set the title of the backBarButtonItem on the same view.